# Changing the color of text inside an Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, colors

I need to change the color of the text inside a listView but I don't know where I should do that.

This is the list where I am storing the values I want to display in the ListView:

```
private List<Map<String, String>> orderList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

This is how I add items to this list (outPut is a simple String):

```
orderList.add(createOrderList("orders", outPut));
```

This is my SimpleAdapter:

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), orderList,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        new String[]{"orders"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

                listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

This is my createOrderList method:

```
private HashMap<String, String> createOrderList(String name, String number) {
    HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
    return employeeNameNo;
}
```

And this is the XML with the ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/lblItem"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_ten"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_ten"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@color/line_color"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Is there anyway to change the color of "android.R.id.text1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom adapter. In getView you'll be ablevto customize lime you want.
You can extend ArrayAdapter for it.

Comment: @MarcosGuimaraes heck this out http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter You should also consider using RecycleListView for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

1)Use A Custom Adaptor

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
    }

    Item p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryId);
        TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

        if (tt1 != null) {
            tt1.setText(p.getId());
        }

        if (tt2 != null) {
            tt2.setText(p.getCategory().getId());
        }

        if (tt3 != null) {
            tt3.setText(p.getDescription());
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

you can set Text Color like this

tt1.setTextColor(Color.Blue);

In Your Activity

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);


      ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this,     R.layout.itemlistrow,             List<yourItem>);

 yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I call this custom adapter in my Activity using the code I have?

Comment: ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);

// get data from the table by the ListAdapter
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, List<yourItem>);

yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom XML file for your Listview item.

listview_item.xml:

Give your customised color and size to text in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

Now use this file to show your listview items with array Adapter like:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_item, orderList);


            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But what is "orders" in this case?

Comment: orders is nothing but orderList